# richfaces external filtering: does not execute filterMethod

Tags: java, ejb, richfaces

I have a filter with richfaces 3.3 which does not execute the method given in `filterMethod`.

The filter:

```
         <r:column filterMethod="#{orderSearchFilter.filterStateText}" >
             <f:facet name="header">
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{orderSearchFilter.filterValueStateText}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{orderSearchFilter.filterListStateTexts}" />
                    <a:support event="onchange" reRender="orders,dataScroller_foot" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{_data.status}"/>
         </r:column>
```

The filtering Bean:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;

import ch.ildsoftware.gvs.order.OrderItem;


@Name("orderSearchFilter")
public class OrderSearchFilter {

private ArrayList<SelectItem> filterListStateTexts = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
private String filterValueInventoryNr="";
private String filterValueSerialNr="";
private SelectionStateText filterValueStateText;


public OrderSearchFilter() {
    for(SelectionStateText sT : SelectionStateText.values()) {
        SelectItem select = new SelectItem();
        select.setLabel(sT.label());
        select.setValue(sT);
        filterListStateTexts.add(select);
    }
}

public ArrayList<SelectItem> getFilterListStateTexts() {
    return filterListStateTexts;
}

public String getFilterValueInventoryNr() {
    return filterValueInventoryNr;
}

public void setFilterValueInventoryNr(String filterValueInventoryNr) {
    this.filterValueInventoryNr = filterValueInventoryNr;
}

public String getFilterValueSerialNr() {
    return filterValueSerialNr;
}

public void setFilterValueSerialNr(String filterValueSerialNr) {
    this.filterValueSerialNr = filterValueSerialNr;
}

public SelectionStateText getFilterValueStateText() {
    return filterValueStateText;
}

public void setFilterValueStateText(SelectionStateText filterValueStateText) {
    this.filterValueStateText = filterValueStateText;
}

public Boolean filterStateText(Object current) {
    OrderItem item = (OrderItem) current;
    SelectionStateText state = getFilterValueStateText();
    for(String status : state.states()) {
        if (status.isEmpty() || status.equals(item.getStatus()))
            return true; 
    }
    return false;
}

public Boolean getFilterStateText(Object current) {
    OrderItem item = (OrderItem) current;
    SelectionStateText state = getFilterValueStateText();
    for(String status : state.states()) {
        if (status.isEmpty() || status.equals(item.getStatus()))
            return true; 
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

I found different implementations, that's why there is the method written twice, once with `get` prefix. Now I basically kept to following example: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/filteringFeature.jsf?tab=ex-usage&cid=4110192

In the debugger I can see, that the filter value is set (`setFilterValueStateText`), but neither of the filter methods is called.

All I can see, that it jumps into the `modify()` method of another class, where the string after `filterMethod` pops up as a `FilterField` (not `ExtendedFilterField`), but there the filtering bean is not accessible with its current values. In this class the other filters are handled:

```
public class OrderSearchDataModel extends QueryDataModel implements Modifiable 
{

private OrderSearchCriteria orderSearchCriteria;

public OrderSearchDataModel(OrderSearch query)
{
    super(query);
}

@Override
public void modify(List<FilterField> filterFields,
        List<SortField2> sortFields)
{   
    if (filterFields != null && !filterFields.isEmpty()) {

        ExtendedFilterField extendedFilterField = null;
        String value = null;
        Expression expression = null;
        String expressionStr = null;
        orderSearchCriteria = new OrderSearchCriteria();

        for (FilterField filterField : filterFields) {
            if (filterField instanceof ExtendedFilterField) {
                extendedFilterField = (ExtendedFilterField) filterField;
                value = extendedFilterField.getFilterValue();
                if (value != null && !value.equals("")) {
                    expression = extendedFilterField.getExpression();
                    expressionStr = expression.getExpressionString();
                    if (!expression.isLiteralText()) {
                        expressionStr = expressionStr.
                                replaceAll("[#|$]{1}\\{.*?\\.", "").
                                replaceAll("\\}", "");
                    }
                    if (expressionStr.equals("inventoryNr"))
                        orderSearchCriteria.setInventoryNr(value);
                    if (expressionStr.equals("serialNr"))
                        orderSearchCriteria.setSerialNr(value);

                    OrderSearch orderSearch = (OrderSearch) getQuery();
                    orderSearch.setSearchCriteria(orderSearchCriteria);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Set<SortField2> validSortFields = new HashSet<SortField2>();
    for (SortField2 sortField : sortFields)
    {
        if (!sortField.getOrdering().equals(Ordering.UNSORTED))
            validSortFields.add(sortField);
    }

    if (validSortFields.size() == 1)
    {
        SortField2 sortfield = validSortFields.iterator().next();
        ValueExpression expression = (ValueExpression) sortfield
                .getExpression();
        OrderSearchField field = (OrderSearchField) expression.getValue(FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getELContext());
        boolean asc = sortfield.getOrdering().equals(Ordering.ASCENDING);
        Sorting<OrderSearchField> sorting = new Sorting<OrderSearchField>(
                field, asc);
        OrderSearch orderSearch = (OrderSearch) getQuery();
        orderSearch.setSorting(sorting);
    }
    else if(validSortFields.size() > 1) throw new FacesException("multiple column sorting is not suported");

}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a solution to the question, but a workaround, which is somewhat acceptabel.
I basically discarded the external filter and switched to an internal one:

My filter looks like this now:

```
         <r:column
            filterBy="#{_data.status}"
            filterValue="#{orderSearchFilter.filterValueStateText}" >
             <f:facet name="header">
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{orderSearchFilter.filterValueStateText}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{orderSearchFilter.filterListStateTexts}" />
                    <a:support event="onchange" ignoreDupResponses="true" requestDelay="700"
                        reRender="resultCount,orders,dataScroller_head,dataScroller_foot" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{_data.status}"/>
         </r:column>
```

And it's handled here (comlete class is visible above):

```
                if (expressionStr.equals("inventoryNr"))
                        orderSearchCriteria.setInventoryNr(value);
                if (expressionStr.equals("serialNr"))
                        orderSearchCriteria.setSerialNr(value);
                if (expressionStr.equals("status")) {
                        SelectionStateText state = SelectionStateText.valueOf(value);
                        orderSearchCriteria.setStateTexts(state.states());
                }
                    OrderSearch orderSearch = (OrderSearch) getQuery();
                    orderSearch.setSearchCriteria(orderSearchCriteria);
```

Now I have a functioning filter, only that there is an unneccessary field below the selection list:

[image: richfaces data table headers with filter workaround]